# Gulp + Browsersync how to start Chrome with flags

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I am looking to have gulp start browser sync in chrome with the flag --remote-debugging-port=9222 in order that I can connect via VS Code Chrome Devtools Extension.

My gulp file (partial) looks like:

`gulp.task("browserSync", function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "src"
    },
    browser: "google chrome",
  });
});`

Failed attempts

browser: "google chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"

browser: "chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222"